# How do I add a role via a C# bot in Discord?

Tags: c#, bots, discord, discord.net

The Discord API says nothing about adding roles. Is that possible?

Comment: Already stated by tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, look into the method under `SocketGuildUser` [here](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuildUser.html).

You will see a method named `AddRoleAsync()` OR `AddRolesAsync()`. That is the one that you would be looking for.
The method takes in a `IRole` datatype, and that would be the role you want to assign the user to. Also, your `SocketGuildUser` should be the user you want to target.

[Also, this documentation and answer is based on Discord.NET Version 1 and above]